# Keystore + CSR created on dev system does not work on remote (AWS) Tomcat

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, tomcat, tomcat8, keytool

I am facing very odd situation. I have created keystore + CSR using keytool command in my local/dev machine.

I got the SSL certificate from `https://www.thawte.com/`. I have successfully imported cert and configured on local/dev tomcat. And It shows certificate information too, which means certificate is fine.

But, the problem is when I configure same imported keystore to Tomcat in AWS then the Tomcat does not responds the request.

Can anyone help me here ?

Thanks

Comment: Include in the body of the question the output of `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect` to both your dev system and the AWS hosted system.